# Display selected BACS account from matching order item meta value using Woocommerce hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, payment-method

Based on "[Select BACS account to show in thankyou page in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048703/select-bacs-account-to-show-in-thankyou-page-in-woocommerce)" answer code to one of my questions, I have changed the Woocommerce core file "class-wc-gateway-bacs.php" In order to select the correct bank account displayed on thankyou page, that matches with the variation attribute of a purchased product.

I have added the next code to "class-wc-gateway-bacs.php" after line 255:

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {$sede = $item->get_meta("pa_sede");};
if ( $bacs_account->sort_code != $sede ) { continue; };
```

So the modified code section from `bank_details()` function, results as follows:

```
            foreach ( $bacs_accounts as $bacs_account ) {
                $bacs_account = (object) $bacs_account;

                foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {$sede = $item->get_meta("pa_sede");};
                if ( $bacs_account->sort_code != $sede ) { continue; };

                if ( $bacs_account->account_name ) {
                    $account_html .= '<h3 class="wc-bacs-bank-details-account-name">' . wp_kses_post( wp_unslash( $bacs_account->account_name ) ) . ':</h3>' . PHP_EOL;
                }
                $account_html .= '<ul class="wc-bacs-bank-details order_details bacs_details">' . PHP_EOL;
                // BACS account fields shown on the thanks page and in emails.
                $account_fields = apply_filters(
                    'woocommerce_bacs_account_fields',
                    array(
                        'bank_name'      => array(
                            'label' => __( 'Bank', 'woocommerce' ),
                            'value' => $bacs_account->bank_name,
                        ),
                        'account_number' => array(
                            'label' => __( 'Account number', 'woocommerce' ),
                            'value' => $bacs_account->account_number,
                        ),
                        'sort_code'      => array(
                            'label' => $sortcode,
                            'value' => $bacs_account->sort_code,
                        ),
                        'iban'           => array(
                            'label' => __( 'IBAN', 'woocommerce' ),
                            'value' => $bacs_account->iban,
                        ),
                        'bic'            => array(
                            'label' => __( 'BIC', 'woocommerce' ),
                            'value' => $bacs_account->bic,
                        ),
                    ),
                    $order_id
                );
                foreach ( $account_fields as $field_key => $field ) {
                    if ( ! empty( $field['value'] ) ) {
                        $account_html .= '<li class="' . esc_attr( $field_key ) . '">' . wp_kses_post( $field['label'] ) . ': <strong>' . wp_kses_post( wptexturize( $field['value'] ) ) . '</strong></li>' . PHP_EOL;
                        $has_details   = true;
                    }
                }
                $account_html .= '</ul>';
            }
```

However, Is not a good practice and I would like to use a hooked function in the instead of messing with class-wc-gateway-bacs.php.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following hooked function will avoid overwriting Woocommerce `class-wc-gateway-bacs.php` core file, using a specific variation attribute value from order items to display the matching  bank account(s) in Woocommerce Order received page *(thankyou)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bacs_accounts', 'filter_woocommerce_bacs_accounts_callback', 10, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_bacs_accounts_callback( $bacs_accounts ){
    if ( empty($bacs_accounts) ) {
        return $bacs_accounts; // Exit
    }

    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
        $endpoint = 'order-received';
    } elseif( is_wc_endpoint_url('view-order') ) {
        $endpoint = 'view-order';
    } else {
        return $bacs_accounts; // Exit
    }

    // Get the WC_Order Object
    $order = wc_get_order( get_query_var($endpoint) );

    $sort_codes = []; // Initializing variable array

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $sort_codes[] = $item->get_meta("pa_sede");
    }

    if ( empty($sort_codes) ) {
        return $bacs_accounts; // Exit
    }

    // Loop through Bacs accounts
    foreach ( $bacs_accounts as $key => $bacs_account ) {
        $bacs_account = (object) $bacs_account;

        // Remove the non matching bank accounts
        if ( ! in_array($bacs_account->sort_code, $sort_codes ) ) {
            unset($bacs_accounts[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $bacs_accounts;
}
```

Code goes in `function.php` file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*. Tested and  work *(it should work with your product attribute for variation **`pa_sede`**)*.

Comment: Working great. Thanks a lot!.Just one more little thing, is it possible to hide the sort code column?

Comment: @Roasty I don't know... Try to show how or where this is done in the core code file, asking a new question. Then notify me here.

Comment: Dear Loic. Instead of asking a new one, I edited this question as hiding the sort code column should be part of the same problem I am presenting.

Comment: @Roasty Multiple questions at once is not allowed in StackOverFlow and even more editing your question. So please roll back and ask a new question in a new thread.