# How to show/hide bacs account in woocommerce depending on the custom field value?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to display a specific bacs account info based on meta field value? For example, I add a vendor meta field on each product then display the corresponding bacs account info for that vendor on the thank you page and order page.

Comment: See [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174664/3730754) that might be helpful