# Filter which BACS account information is sent to users via email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Implemented the following solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174664/1759546 with success but, how could one apply the same logic in the order confirmation emails that are sent to the users? I'm trying to send just one of many accounts available, depending on meta data from order.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was being dumb.

We just have to pass a second argument to `woocommerce_bacs_accounts` which is the order_id. And as the filter runs inside the order_email it will apply the same rules.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bacs_accounts', 'filter_woocommerce_bacs_accounts_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_bacs_accounts_callback( $bacs_accounts, $order_id ){
    if ( empty($bacs_accounts) ) {
        return $bacs_accounts; // Exit
    }

    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
        $endpoint = 'order-received';
        // Get the WC_Order Object
        $order = wc_get_order( get_query_var($endpoint) );
    } elseif( is_wc_endpoint_url('view-order') ) {
        $endpoint = 'view-order';
        // Get the WC_Order Object
        $order = wc_get_order( get_query_var($endpoint) );
    } else if ($order_id){
        // Get the WC_Order Object
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id );
    }

    $sort_codes = []; // Initializing variable array

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $sort_codes[] = $item->get_meta("pa_sede");
    }

    if ( empty($sort_codes) ) {
        return $bacs_accounts; // Exit
    }

    // Loop through Bacs accounts
    foreach ( $bacs_accounts as $key => $bacs_account ) {
        $bacs_account = (object) $bacs_account;

        // Remove the non matching bank accounts
        if ( ! in_array($bacs_account->sort_code, $sort_codes ) ) {
            unset($bacs_accounts[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $bacs_accounts;
}
```

Comment: i tried this but the code doesn't work on emails.
1 gets passed but the function expects 2. so i edited the code to be 
"function filter_woocommerce_bacs_accounts_callback( $bacs_accounts, $order_id = null )"
the thank-you page works, but emails don't get sent since
"PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_items() on null"