# Get slug from a woocommerce product using a product id

Tags: wordpress

**I want to get the slug of each product in a woocommerce order/purchase of current user.**

**Steps i took**

1.I fetched current user's order.

2.Then I get items/products from the order

```
$args = array(
    'customer_id' => $user->ID
    'status' => 'completed'
);
//getting the orders 
$orders = wc_get_orders($args);
$orderInfo = [
'id' => [],
'name' => [],
'slug' => []
];
foreach($orders as $order){
  foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
    array_push( $orderInfo['id'], $item->get_product_id() );
    array_push( $orderInfo['name'], $item->get_name() );
    array_push( $orderInfo['slug'], $item->get_slug() );
  }
}
```

After fetching products i am able to get product id and name. But when using **$item->get_slug**, I am facing this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   WC_Order_Item_Product::get_slug()

What wrong am i doing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095190/woocommerce-how-do-i-get-the-product-slug-from-the-id/34095711

Comment: Facing this error now:- 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property WC_Order_Item_Product::$id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
$product = get_post( $item->get_product_id() );
$slug = $product->post_name;
array_push( $orderInfo['slug'], $slug );
```